# node.js express and mongoose defaulting to case sensitive URLs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a node.js / express / mongo + mongoose project and I have a problem with case sensitive URLs. I want to be able to go to `/location/london` however, the `:name` I am calling from the database is actually `London`

my routes.js file is as follows:

```
app.get('/location/:name', function(req, res) {
  mongoose.model('locations').find({name: req.params.name}, function(err, locations) {
    res.send(locations);
  })
})
```

`/location/London` will work however `/location/london/` will not.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Just getting to grips with Express. Although the [express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set) say URL's are case sensititve by default.

> case sensitive routing | Boolean |    Enable case sensitivity.
>
> Disabled. Treats "/Foo" and "/foo" as the same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in `req.params.name` you can pass in `req.params.name.toLowerCase()`. That should solve your issue.
Or you should make sure your routes are set to be case insensitive, and that you restart your server so the configs are refreshed.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, I was still passing in /location/london and it wouldn't return anything but London would since that is what it is in the mongo database. For the time being, I'm not sure if it's the correct way of doing things but I just added a slug so I could use that instead and go to /location/london and then use name: London elsewhere in the template